# Add respective dataframes in list together in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, addition

I have 2 lists of dataframes in R (where the respective dataframes in each list are the same size). Is it possible to add the respective dataframnes in each list together in one line.

e.g. say we had

```
list1 <- list('a' = data.frame('x'=c(0,1),'y'=c(2,0)), 'b' = data.frame('x'=c(1,1),'y'=c(1,1)))
list2 <- list('a' = data.frame('x'=c(1,2),'y'=c(1,1)), 'b' = data.frame('x'=c(0,1),'y'=c(0,1)))
```

So list1 is:

```
$a
 x y
 0 2
 1 0

$b
 x y
 1 1
 1 1
```

And list2 is:

```
$a
 x y
 1 1
 2 1

$b
 x y
 0 0
 1 1
```

The final output would be:

```
$a
 x y
 1 3
 3 1

$b
 x y
 1 1
 2 2
```

Could obviously do this in two seperate lines by doing:

```
listOutput <- list()
listOutput[['a']] <- list1[['a']] + list2[['a']]
listOutput[['b']] <- list1[['b']] + list2[['b']]
```

but is there a simple way to do this in one line, maybe using lapply?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a way that preserves names:

```
mapply(function(x, y) x + y, list1, list2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE, USE.NAMES=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that is very specific to your question. In other words, it assumes:

1. You have two lists
2. Each list has identical elements
3. The elements can be converted to matrices

The code:

```
lapply(1:2, function(i)list1[[i]] + list2[[i]])
[[1]]
  x y
1 1 3
2 3 1

[[2]]
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks Andrie that works, but is there a way of retaining the names of the dataframes within the list? (in this case a & b)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should be able to do it with a combination of `unlist` and `relist`, but it doesn't seem to work as documented:

```
relist(unlist(list1)+unlist(list2),skeleton=list1)
$a
   x    y <NA> <NA> 
   1    3    3    1 

$b
   x    y <NA> <NA> 
   1    2    1    2
```