# How can I add vector elements to corresponding vectors in lists?

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a vectors of variable length in lists and a vector, somewhat like this:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- lapply(as.list(sample(1:10, 10, repl=TRUE)),
            function(x) sample(1:10, x, repl=TRUE))
y <- sample(1:10, 10, repl=TRUE)
```

I need to add each element of `y` to a corresponding vector in `x`. Currently I accomplish this as so:

```
newList <- list()

for (i in seq_along(y)) {
  newList <- c(newList, list(y[i] + x[[i]]))
}

> x[1:2]
[[1]]
[1]  1  3  2  7  4  8  5  8 10

[[2]]
[1]  4  8 10

> y[1:2]
[1] 4 8

> newList
[[1]]
[1]  5  7  6 11  8 12  9 12 14

[[2]]
[1] 12 16 18

[[3]]
[1] 13 17 12 13
...
```

Is there a better way, perhaps using a `lapply`-like function?

Comment: `Map("+",x,y)` will do it.

Comment: I'm just trying to find if this is a duplicate first as I'm sure I've answered something like this before - it's essentially the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945339/how-do-i-apply-an-index-vector-over-a-list-of-vectors but with a different function applied. Also very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215785/add-respective-dataframes-in-list-together-in-r

Comment: You're right, but I think there is some value in having questions asked differently even with the same answer. When looking for questions similar to mine, I didn't come across those. And for the second, I wouldn't have thought to apply that solution.

Comment: `Map` is a wrapper for `mapply("+", x, y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to previous questions, which use `Map` or `mapply` to operate on two lists/vectors of the same length in tandem:

[How do I apply an index vector over a list of vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945339/how-do-i-apply-an-index-vector-over-a-list-of-vectors)
[Add respective dataframes in list together in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215785/add-respective-dataframes-in-list-together-in-r)

For this specific case, try:

```
Map("+",x,y)

#[[1]]
#[1]  5  7  6 11  8 12  9 12 14
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 12 16 18
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 13 17 12 13
```